# How to scroll horizontally a dynamic table in selenium web driver in java

Tags: selenium

[image]

How to scroll this horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you could do

```
# driver init
# load page
scrollable_div_element = driver.find_element_by_id("hotTableParentDiv")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[0].scrollWidth", scrollable_div_element)
```

where `arguments[0].scrollWidth` is the max scroll width for `scrollable_div_element`. Therefore this example would horizontally scroll your div fully to the right edge.